# Showing the following linear operator is bounded

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Given a bounded linear operator $T:L^2([0,1])\to L^2([0,1])$ which maps $C^0([0,1])$ functions to $C^0([0,1])$ functions, I'm trying to show that $T$ is bounded as an operator on $C^0([0,1])$ in the sup norm $||f||_{\infty} = \sup_{x\in [0,1]} |f(x)|$.

Clearly if $f\in C^0([0,1])$, then $||f||_{\infty}$ exists, is finite, and is actually attained at some point in the interval by $f$ (as $f$ will be continuous on a closed interval). Similar for $||Tf||_{\infty}$. However, I'm not sure how I can use the above and the fact that

$$||Tf||_2 \leq C||f||_2, \quad C \in\mathbb{R}^+$$

to show that 
$$||Tf||_{\infty} \leq \tilde{C}||f||_{\infty}, \quad \tilde{C} \in \mathbb{R}^+$$

Does anyone have any advice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\{f_k\}$ be a sequence of functions in $C^0([0,1])$ which converges in the uniform norm to a function $f$.  By hypothesis each $Tf_k$ belongs to $C^0([0,1])$. Assume in addition that $Tf_k$ converges in the uniform norm to a function $g$.

Since 
$$\|Tf_k - Tf\|_2 \le C \|f_k - f\|_2 \le C \|f_k - f\|_\infty$$
you have $Tf_k \to Tf$  in $L^2([0,1])$. This leads to the following situation:

- $Tf_k \to g$ uniformly on $[0,1]$, and
- $Tf_k \to Tf$ in $L^2([0,1])$.

By hypothesis $Tf$ is continuous so you conclude that $Tf = g$ in $C^0([0,1])$.

The boundedness of $T$ follows from the closed graph theorem.

Comment: I thought $||\cdot ||_2 \leq ||\cdot ||_{\infty}$? How did you get the last step in your first inequality? Also, by "uniform norm", do you mean $||\cdot ||_{\infty}$?

Comment: The last step in the first inequality is precisely $\|\cdot\|_2 \le \|\cdot\|_\infty$. I don't  get the question.

Comment: The uniform norm is indeed $\|\cdot\|_\infty$.

Comment: Oops, I meant $||\cdot ||_{\infty} \leq ||\cdot ||_2$ in my above comment. My bad.

Comment: That one's not true at all.

Comment: Aren't they equivalent, though? With $||\cdot ||_{\infty} \leq ||\cdot ||_2 \leq \sqrt{n} ||\cdot ||_{\infty}$ when we are in $\mathbb{R}^n$? I guess we are just in $\mathbb{R}$ here so what you said above holds?

Comment: ??? The normed space is $C^0([0,1])$, not $\mathbf R$.

Comment: Never mind, I misread when I was writing that comment (was looking at $C \in \mathbb{R}^+$ when typing it and got confused). Sorry.